# Update multiple table with different WHERE clause in one query

Tags: mysql

I want to **combine** three different UPDATE queries, in **different table**, with **different WHERE** conditions, into a single mySql query. Is it possible?

> Reason: send 1 request to mySql server is faster than sending 3
>   requests separately :)

```
UPDATE client SET clientCount = clientCount + 1 WHERE clientType = 2
UPDATE storage SET soldItem = soldItem + 1 WHERE itemType = 5
UPDATE employee SET doWork = 1, totalSale = totalSale + 1 WHERE employeeId = 12
```

The UPDATE statements are independent, and are not related to each other. I tried to find some solution, however, the

```
UPDATE client, storage, employee SET client.clientCount = ... , storage.soldItem = ... WHERE ... ? ? ? ...
```

does not fit to my case as my three UPDATE statements are independent...

Is it possible to combine 3 independents queries into a 1 query?

Comment: Pretty sure there's no way to do that since the tables are not related... try creating a stored procedure or function and call it, you will still have to write these 3 queries in it, but you save 2 calls.

Comment: @booyanjiong i'm not sure how one update statement can work on 3 different tables but stored process is one option to call multiple update statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `stored procedure` with all these `update statements` and call the `stored procedure` from your `code`.